# connection time out putty/bitvise

Tags: ssh, putty, webserver, bitvise

The error:

> Connection Failed. FlowSocketConnector: failed to connect to target address. Windows error 10060. A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection because connected host has failed to respond.

I installed ubuntu on an oracle virtual box, and I attempted to connect to the ssh through bitvise and also putty. In both instances I received the same error. I attempted many fixes but with no results whatsoever. I double-checked my IP address and my available ports; I made sure the ssh is enabled and active; I turned off windows firewall; I increased the timer in my bitvise options to 10 seconds, and at one instance to 25 seconds. I restarted the ssh and I also restarted my router as a last resort.

I would highly appreciate any other suggestions/ or further clarifications on what could be the problem.

PS. I'm a newbie. It was yesterday when I learned what a port was.

Comment: What address are you trying to connect to? Which networking mode (NAT, bridge, host) have you selected in th VM"s network settings? Have you checked that the VM actually has an SSH service running (systemctl status ssh), and that it doesn't block the connections in its firewall (probably `ufw`)?

Comment: I have fixed the issues. After changing the network type to bridged. The effect only took form when I restarted my system. Should I delete the post, or leave it so that someone else may ask me for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simply restarting my system after changing the network type to bridged (the preferred type to establish an ssh connection). Moreover, if the problem persists like it did on my Macbook, pinging the IP address  of the client or the host, from either devices should do the trick.